# Python and webbrowser form fill

Tags: python

Hello how can i make changes in my web browser with python? Like filling forms and pressing Submit?

What lib's should i use? And maybe someone of you have some examples?

Using urllib does not make any changes in opened browser for me

Comment: urllib is not for what you seem to think it's for.

Comment: Does the browser that you're trying to control have a Python API?

Answer (score 1):

Urllib is not intended to do anyting with your browser, but rather to get contents from urls.

To fill in forms and this kind of things, have a look into [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html), to scrap the webpages, consider using [pyquery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery).

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is great for this. It's a browser automation tool that you can use to launch a browser (any major browser or a 'headless' one), navigate to a url, and interact with the page.

It's used primarily for testing web code against multiple browsers, but is also very useful for 'scraping' pages and automating mundane tasks.

Here are the python docs: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html